# UserControl OnPropertyChanged issue

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have `OnPropertyChanged` method in my UserControl class:

```
private static void OnColorChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorPicker colorPicker = (ColorPicker)sender;

        Color oldColor = (Color)e.OldValue;
        Color newColor = (Color)e.NewValue;
        colorPicker.Red = newColor.R;
        colorPicker.Green = newColor.G;
        colorPicker.Blue = newColor.B;

        colorPicker._previousColors.Push(oldColor); //don't update if undo command executed
        colorPicker.OnColorChanged(oldColor, newColor);
    }
```

_previousColors is:

```
private Stack<Color> _previousColors = new Stack<Color>();
```

and i don't want update this stack if undo command executed:

```
private void UndoCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = _previousColors.Count > 1;
    }

    private void UndoCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var color = _previousColors.Pop();
        this.Color = color;

    }
```

How can I realize this condition in `OnColorChanged` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could have private bool (lets call it isUndoing) which gets set true at the begin of the undo execute and is reset to false at the end.  In the OnColorChanged, look at the value of isUndoing and take appropriate action.  Would this not work?

Also, I agree with Rachel, upvoting and Answer marking are your friends.  Every time you give someone credit for good posts, people are that much more likely to help you in the future,